# got error while creating folder in samsung and one plus-x device sdcard

Tags: android, sd-card, oneplusx

> ```
> **Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**
>   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
>   at com.snatik.storage.Storage.copy(Storage.java:278) 
>   at com.snatik.storage.Storage.move(Storage.java:293) 
>   at com.snatik.storage.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:90) 
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233) 
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21211) 
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
> ```

Comment: Have you add: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  in your manifest

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting any more on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of you don't have permission to do this on SD Card, on Android devices after version 5.0, you have to get permission's at runtime not just ask them in AndroidManifest.xml
for getting android permissions at runtime i suggest you to use EasyPermissions library https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
then you can handle situations like permissionGranted or permissionDenied like below:

```
String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.camera_and_location_rationale),
            RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION, perms);

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // Forward results to EasyPermissions
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been granted
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been denied
    // ...
}
```